# Redeclare a Variable or Object after Declaration in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, variables, object, dynamic, declare

Is there a possible way that I can set for example a public dummy Variable or Object
`Public Connection`, and after then in the code/class I decide to set it like:

```
Connection = SqlConnection
```

or (depends on)

```
Connection = OdbcConnection
```

so that I do not have to declare them all from the start like:

```
dim mySqlConnection as SqlConnection
dim myOdbcConnection as OdbcConnection
```

Any hint is welcome, also if it is a link. I tried to google it, but I think I'm using the wrong query.

Answer (score 0):

In this case yes, you can declare you connection as `System.Data.Common.DbConnection`.

As both `SqlConnection` and `OdbcConnection` inherit from `DbConnection`, you can declare your variable with the parent type and instantiate it with the inherited type.

You will be limited to use the common (declared at parent) methods though.

Comment: ok, thanks very much, i give it a try, do you know any other general method?

Comment: You can obviously declare anything as `Object` and create an instance of any class you like but it does not seem necessary if you have a common parent.

Comment: i cannot do it right now, (for me it's a real brainer). i need to research how to instantiate that in a class. if i have news i return back here, but thanks a lot for your information!